# Java parsing large json

Tags: java, json, parsing, openstreetmap

I want to parse json file from OSM servers. It may vary from few Kbs to 10-20 Mbs. I'm using GSON right now but I'm facing some performance issues when parsing large file (like 10 Mbs). It takes about 10 seconds only for parsing in streaming mode:

```
JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new StringReader(data));
    try {
        reader.beginObject();
        while(reader.hasNext()){
            String name = reader.nextName();
            if(name.equals("elements")){
                reader.beginArray();
                while(reader.hasNext()){
                    String type = null;
                    Long id = 0L;
                    Double lat = 0D;
                    Double lon = 0D;
                    ArrayList<Long> nodes = new ArrayList<>();
                    Tags tags = null;
                    reader.beginObject();
                    while(reader.hasNext()) {
                        name = reader.nextName();
                        switch (name) {
                            case "type":
                                type = reader.nextString();
                                break;
                            case "tags":
                                reader.beginObject();
                                while (reader.hasNext()) {
                                    name = reader.nextName();
                                    if (name.equals("highway"))
                                        tags = new Tags(reader.nextString());
                                    else
                                        reader.skipValue();
                                }
                                reader.endObject();
                                break;
                            default:
                                reader.skipValue();
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                    reader.endObject();
                }
                reader.endArray();
            }
            else{
                reader.skipValue();
            }
        }
        reader.endObject();
        reader.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

For now it is an bottleneck for my application. I have tried already some other libraries but there wasn't any improvement. Is there anything I'm doing wrong or is there some special way to parse large json data?

Comment: Maybe you want to tell us what you are trying to achieve. There might be better ways available. Parsing raw OSM data in JS sounds wrong.

Comment: It's Java not JS. I want to get way types and some other basic data from OSM in given area.

Answer (score 2):

JSON is not made for fast parsing (and is none of the file types usually offered for OSM). Maybe you should take a look at [OSM PBF](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/PBF_Format) instead. Although it is compressed it should be faster to parse than JSON.

Alternatively don't reinvent the wheel but instead use a tool such as [osmium](http://osmcode.org/osmium-tool/) or [osmosis](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis) for parsing OSM PBF or XML.

Another solution is to create a [Overpass API](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API) request for the exact element types you are interested in. This has the advantage that the file you are going to parse contains only relevant data.

Comment: I'm using Overpass API to get only interesting data already. Thank you for information about PBF format. It may be a solution.